# Как в android создать стабильный сервис (службу)?

Tags: java, android, service, background, таймер

В программе работают 8 таймеров (Chronometer) с оповещениями. Программа запускает сервис (воспроизведение звука и моргание вспышки) при активации ключевых 2-х таймеров. В foreground режиме проблем нет, все четко работает. Но при сворачивании программы в фон начинаются проблемы. Сервис работает 3-4 часа (если программу добавить в список неубиваемых), потом все-равно убивается... Причем, при восстановлении программы из таска таймеры продолжают правильно работать, но сервис уже умер(( 
Как можно надежно залочить сервис? Он должен работать круглосуточно. Принудительное восстановление сервиса не очень подходит, т.к. каждый из них запускается со стартовыми значениями и при восстановлении их нужно менять, а брать их неоткуда..

Comment: Пока работает, если сервис запустить в режиме startForeground. Тестируем..

Comment: Даже в режиме startForeground через некоторое время бесследно иссчезает.. Буду играться с флагами самовосстановления..

Comment: Как оказалось, любые сервисы, запущенные из активити в любом случае убиваются при убивании активити, их запустившей.. Теперь отрабатываю сценарий запуска сервиса из BroadcastReceiver, который теоретически должен жить даже после удаления активити..

Comment: На сегодняшний момент, самым стабильным способом стало использование Alarm Manager'a. Он относится к системным службам, поэтому система его не трогает и срабатывает очень точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сегодняшний момент, самым стабильным способом стало использование Alarm Manager'a. Он относится к системным службам, поэтому система его не трогает и срабатывает очень точно. Работает через Broadcast Receiver, что позволяет не зависеть от жизненного цикла активити. Будильник срабатывает даже если активити уничтожено системой.
Принцип такой: Из активити отправляем интент с начальными данными, его перехватывает наш ресивер и используя полученные в интент данные "заводит" будильник с нужными операциями (в том числе и повторный запуск активити, если оно уничтожено). Код постить не буду, думаю, и так понятно.

Comment: Хоть он таким и остался, но уже ой как не надёжен( Особенно на китайцах и Samsung

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте свой сервис с флагом `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` - это не избавляет сервис от убивания его осью, но гарантирует его повторный запуск до тех пор пока не будет вызван `stopSelf()`

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)

А чисто неубиваемый сервис создать невозможно. Android так устроен, что любой сервис, активити может быть убит системой принудительно в зависимости от текущей ситуации

Comment: Попробую. А как быть со входными данными? Они подавались через Intent. Сделать получение через SharedPreference, а текущие сохранять в SharedPreferense при Service.onDestroy?

Comment: `Intent` на запуск сервиса будет перезапущен со старыми значениями (по идее). Никогда не пользовался, так что надо проверять